# Using different versions of python with virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I've got various versions of python installed on my Mac using Macports. When I've selected python 2.7 via `$ port select python python27`, virtualenvwrapper works perfectly.

But if I select another version of python, i.e. 2.6, virtualenvwrapper generates an error message: ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader

I checked my .profile and it's setting `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to `/opt/local/bin/python`, so it seems to me virtualenvwrapper should work regardless of which python I've selected.

Any idea what would cause virtualenvwrapper to generate a .hook_loader error when I switch python versions?

Comment: Without going through `port select ...` and sticking with your base 2.7, does just running `mkvirtualenv --python /path/to/python2.6` work? 

It should automatically switch to (and set up the environment with) the correct interpreter. On my system (set up with homebrew), `mkvirtualenv -p python2.6` works fine.

Comment: I don't get the hook_loader error, but it's complaining about lack of DEST_DIR $ mkvirtualenv --python /opt/local/bin/python2.7
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/local/bin/python2.7
You must provide a DEST_DIR

Comment: Whoops, sorry--left out the key argument! That should be `mkvirtualenv --python /path/to/python2.6 env_name`. mkvirtualenv makes a folder called "env_name" in your `$WORKON_HOME`, which gets passed on to virtualenv as its `DEST_DIR` argument. Without specifying a name, it would have a hard time figuring out where to set things up, that's for sure.

Comment: Duh. I should have caught that. Yes, that worked. Guess the answer is to leave port select to python27 and run mkvirtualenv with the --python flag when I need to use something else.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I know this is pretty much solved in your comments, but it's mac only,

and even more I think the correct way should be to set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to the real python you are using on the command line.

To be sure you can do `which python`.

Actually, you can even do:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=`which python`
```

On linux I do this in my .bashrc, so all in all, assuming you installed virtualenv and created your first "virtual environment" `virtualenv` (how original)

```
. virtualenv/bin/activate
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs # or whatever else you want
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=`which python`
export PROJECT_HOME=SOMETHING
source $HOME/virtualenv/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh # or wherever else you got that installed
```

(and by the way, you wrote:

> I checked my .profile and it's setting VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON to /opt/local/bin/python, so it seems to me virtualenvwrapper should work regardless of which python I've selected

which is actually the opposite - virtualenv relies on using the correct python (and the packages that go with it) so it's very important to set the python path accordingly.

Even running a py file with a "#!/bin/python" might bring trouble once you are virtualenved!

Comment: Running a few tests on my Mac -- it appears `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` only controls which Python executable is used by `virtualenvwrapper` itself, not the executable that's installed into the virtual environment e.g. when you run `mkproject`. I would love to be wrong but so far it appears the only way to choose a different Python version is to use `-p / --python` in the `virtualenvwrapper` command line.  If that's true, it's kind of a shame.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson  mmmh since then I stopped using virtualenvwrapper - not finding much need for it anymore - I have no easy way to double check quickly, but you might indeed be right... Also on MAC I use brew now...

Comment: Same as @ChrisJohnson on ubuntu. had my `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` set to python2, but `mkvirtualenv` was creating virtualenvs with python3.

Answer (score 65):

You can select the python version explicitly

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3 venvname
```

or

```
mkvirtualenv -p python2.7 venvname
```

Comment: Perfect for being able to easily run multiple different environements on a single development machine.

Comment: How can I be sure that the virtual environment created has the correct python installed?
If I do `which python` I get: `/home/USER/.virtualenvs/venvname/bin/python`

Comment: @desmond13 type `workon venvname `and `python3 --version`, this should show the python3 version being used

Answer (score 18):

None of these worked.  I installed Python3 first when setting up my osx machine, and pip and all default to that.

First, check which python you have installed:

```
$ `which python` -V
```

If this returns "Python 2.7.12", then you are set to run:

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p `which python` api_server
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python
New python executable in /Users/eric/.virtualenvs/api_server/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /Users/eric/.virtualenvs/api_server/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/eric/.virtualenvs/api_server/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/eric/.virtualenvs/api_server/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/eric/.virtualenvs/api_server/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/eric/.virtualenvs/api_server/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/eric/.virtualenvs/api_server/bin/get_env_details
```

This will also activate the `api_server` workon, which changes your python executable:

```
$ which python
/Users/eric/.virtualenvs/api_server/bin/python
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
```

What does `which python` actually do?  It outputs the directory of the python executables found in your PATH:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

By using `which python`, you are basically passing in `/usr/local/bin/python` to the `-p` option in the mkvirtualenv directory.

What happens when you have more than one python executable returned in `which python`?  Just find the one you want and pass it in:

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 api_server
```

And virtualenvwrapper will end up using that python executable instead.

Answer (score 11):

Confirmed the use of two similarly-named environment variables:

`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` -- which Python version is used by the virtualenvwrapper utility itself. In other words, which version of Python executes `virtualenvwrapper`, as if that Python version had been explicitly named in the `#!` line of the virtualenvwrapper script file.

`VIRTUALENV_PYTHON` -- which Python version will be installed by `virtualenv` when you create a new virtual environment.  Equivalent to `-p / --python` option on the `virtualenv` command line.

And perhaps obviously :) the version of Python run in a virtual environment is the version you install for that environment -- has no relation to the above environment variables after the env is created.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24724360/763269 for how to upgrade Python within a virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

To use multiple versions of python with virtualwrapper you need to **reinstall the virtualwrapper** for that new version with its corresponding pip manager.

Say you just installed Python-3.12.0 then in your terminal you will need to

```
sudo pip3.12 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

then you can proceed to create your environment with the different python version

```
mkvirtualenv sexyspace -p python3.12
workon sexyspace
python
```

Note that just my typing python it will load the correct python version. Also you can `pip install` normally within the environment since it knows that it has to use pip3.12 internally

Answer (score -1):

You (the OP) seem to have installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper with python2.7, and not with python2.6. If python2.6 is called at the moment your shell loads the virtualenvwrapper.sh script, it is unhappy. Pretty straightforward.

`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` is made for those situations. With it, you can make sure you always use the right version of python, and don't have to always add that `-p /path/to/python2.7`

So, I don't agree with Stefano's answer in that case, in the OP's situation, you should have explained clearly in your .bashrc which python to use:

```
...
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/path/to/your/python2.7
source /path/to/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Like that it should be ok all the time! Virtualenvwrapper is done to simplify things.

Also, please note that `/opt/local/bin/python` must be a symlink to the version of python you select with `port python select` (check that with `ls -l /opt/local/bin/python` to be sure).

Comment: I'd like to stress that using the -p flag is a solution if you've got layered terminals that prevent you from setting an environment variable (like I have).

mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 Foo