# Installing python3 in a python2 virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, flask, virtualenv

I have a Flask application that is running in a Python 2 virtual environment.

I'm looking to run a Python 3 program, so I need to install python3 into the virtual environment. How do I do this? Do I have to recreate the environment? Is this a difficult migration?

Comment: That doesn't sound feasible.  You have to pick one python version for a virtual environment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not recommended to mix multiple versions of Python.  In fact, I don't think it's even possible.

Creating a new virtualenv isn't difficult at all:

1. Get the list of modules in the current virtualenv

   ```
   source /path/to/current/bin/activate
   pip freeze > /tmp/requirements.txt
   ```
2. Create a new virtualenv. Either change into a suitable directory before executing the virtualenv command or give a full path.

   ```
   deactivate
   virtualenv -p python3 envname
   ```
3. Install modules

   ```
   source envname/bin/activate
   pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
   ```

That's it.

Comment: wow. yeah. it was that easy. one note... you're `/tmp/requirements.txt` spelling is inconsistent ;-)
Question... How do I verify that that Flask App is using the venv? As long as I source it, is it automatically using it?

Comment: yes, if you source it it will be using the one in the virtualenv