# Run python 2.7 inside python 3x virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-2.x

I have a `python 3.5x` `virtualenv`, I have some older `python 2.7` scripts I'd like to run *inside* this `python 3.5x virtualenv`, but obviously the two environments 2.7 vs 3x scripts are **really different** from simple things like print `""` to `print()` to much more involved things.

Thus, how can I run these `python 2.7 scripts` inside this `python 3.5 env` (best case) without having to completely re-write these `python 2.7` scripts (worse case) or would I have to run these `python 2.7` scripts inside their own virtualenv (somewhat worse case) or something else entirely?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing python3 in a python2 virtual environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390053/installing-python3-in-a-python2-virtual-environment)

Comment: though 2 and 3 are interchanged, it's still the same

Comment: Not sure of the complexity of your python scripts but you could look into this: 
https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html
It does the conversion for you if I understand the documentation correctly.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt - I'll check this out too. Thanks!