# python virtual env succesfully activated via WSL but not working

Tags: python, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

on my windows system I've succesfully installed a virtual environment (python version is 3.9) using windows command prompt

`python -m venv C:\my_path\my_venv`

Always using windows command prompt, I'm able to activate the created venv via

`C:\my_path\my_venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

I am sure the venv is correctly activated since:

1. on the windows terminal, I see the command line is preceded by `(my_venv)`
2. if I activate python from the terminal (`python`) and run the following commands: `import sys` ; `sys.path` I can see, in the list of paths, the desired path `[..., 'C:\\my_path\\my_venv\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', ...]`
3. if I do stuff in the activated venv (like installing packages) everything works and is done inside the venv

To sum up, everything is fine so far.

I also have WSL2 (Ubuntu) and I'd like to activate the same venv using the Ubuntu terminal.
If, from the Ubuntu terminal, I activate the venv

`source /mnt/c/my_path/my_venv/Scripts/activate`

it seems to work since the command line is preceeded by `(my_venv)`, but when I run python (`python3` command) and then run `import sys` ; `sys.path` I see that the system is targeting the base Ubuntu python installation (version 3.8) and not the venv installation:

`['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

The venv is not really activated. Any suggestions to solve the issue?

If it can help, I add a couple of information.

If I try to create a venv directly using the Ubuntu terminal

`python3 -m venv /mnt/c/my_path/my_venv_unix`

and activate it via the Ubuntu terminal (`source /mnt/c/my_path/my_venv_unix/bin/activate`) everything works fine, but that's not what I want: I'd like to use WSL to activate a virtual environment created using windows command prompt, since on my machine I've a lot of venvs created with windows and I don't want to replicate them.

Following the script C:\my_path\my_venv\Scripts\activate (/mnt/c/my_path/my_venv/Scripts/activate using wsl folders naming) (I had to change the EOL from windows to Ubuntu, otherwise the command `source /mnt/c/my_path/my_venv/Scripts/activate` would not have worked)

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

deactivate () {
    # reset old environment variables
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}" ] ; then
        PATH="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "${BASH:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] ; then
        hash -r 2> /dev/null
    fi

    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}" ] ; then
        PS1="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "${1:-}" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV="C:\my_path\my_venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/Scripts:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
# this will fail if PYTHONHOME is set to the empty string (which is bad anyway)
# could use `if (set -u; : $PYTHONHOME) ;` in bash
if [ -n "${PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="${PYTHONHOME:-}"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1:-}"
    PS1="(.venv_ml_dl_gen_purpose) ${PS1:-}"
    export PS1
fi

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "${BASH:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] ; then
    hash -r 2> /dev/null
fi
```

Finally, here also the script /mnt/c/my_path/my_venv_unix/bin/activate

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

deactivate () {
    # reset old environment variables
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}" ] ; then
        PATH="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "${BASH:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] ; then
        hash -r
    fi

    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}" ] ; then
        PS1="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "${1:-}" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV="/mnt/c/my_path/my_venv_unix"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
# this will fail if PYTHONHOME is set to the empty string (which is bad anyway)
# could use `if (set -u; : $PYTHONHOME) ;` in bash
if [ -n "${PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="${PYTHONHOME:-}"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1:-}"
    if [ "x(venv_unix) " != x ] ; then
    PS1="(venv_unix) ${PS1:-}"
    else
    if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
        # special case for Aspen magic directories
        # see https://aspen.io/
        PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
    fi
    fi
    export PS1
fi

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "${BASH:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] ; then
    hash -r
fi
```

Thanks to anyone who wants to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer:*  It's highly recommended to use the Linux version of Python and tools when in WSL.  You'll find a number of posts here on Stack Overflow related to this, but your question is different enough (regarding venv) that it deserves its own answer.

*More Detail:*

Also worth reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42733542/11810933).  In that case, the question was around a dual-boot system and whether or not the same venv could be shared between Windows and Linux.

I know it *seems* like things might be better on WSL, where you can run Windows `.exe`cutables under Linux, but it really isn't for this particular case.

You've solved the first problem, in the difference in line endings, but the next problem that you are facing is the difference in the directory format.  After sourcing `activate`, do an `echo $PATH` and you'll see that the *Windows* style `C:\path\to\the\venv` path has been prepended to your `PATH`.  For WSL, that would need to be `/mnt/c/path/to/the/venv`.

That's not going to work.

Once you fix that (again, by editing `activate`), you are still trying to run `python3`.  The venv executable is actually `python.exe`.  Under WSL, you do have to specify the extension.

So if you:

1. Change the line-endings from CRLF to LF
2. Change the path style in `activate` from Windows to WSL2 format
3. Use the `python.exe` executable

Then you can at least launch the Windows Python version.  Your `import sys; sys.path` will show the Windows paths.

That said, you are almost certainly going to run into additional problems that don't make it worth doing this.  For instance, if a script assumes `python` or `python3`, or even `pip`; then those are going to fail because it needs to call, e.g., `pip.exe`.

Line endings and native code will also be a problem.

For these reasons (and likely more), it's highly recommended to use the Linux version of Python when in WSL.

Comment: The 'long answer' solved my specific problem, thanks! For the future, I will take your advice to use only Linux version of python

Comment: @user17788510 Ah yes, forgot my normal "More Detail" separator line :-)