# Trying to run a venv of python 3.6 on linux as an interpreter but even its activation on terminal is not possible due to the following errors

Tags: linux, python-3.6

The command: pyAI3.6/Scripts/activate
The results:
pyAI3.6/Scripts/activate: line 3: $'\r': command not found
pyAI3.6/Scripts/activate: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r'' 'yAI3.6/Scripts/activate: line 4:` deactivate () {

The command: pyAI3.6/Scripts/activate , works perfectly on windows

Comment: Have you copied the virtual environment from Windows to Linux by simply pasting the directory? If so, please see [How to use the same Python virtualenv on both Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733542/how-to-use-the-same-python-virtualenv-on-both-windows-and-linux) to proper copy the virtual environment from your windows machine to your linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

please use below command to activate:

`source <venv-folder>/bin/activate`