# Activate the virtual environment to run a python script

Tags: python, linux, virtual-environment

I'm trying to run a Python script (written in Pycharm for Windows) in a linux system (laptop without internet connection).
I have my folder with my script (main.py) and my venv folder.
I tried to activate the virtual environment using `source /project/venv/Scripts/activate` and then running `python3 /project/main.py` but here it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`.
I know that the module is in the virtual environment site-packages so I assume that I didn't activate the venv properly. Any help?

Comment: Are you execute a venv created in Windows on a Linux machine? It will not work out of the box, you will need to install all dependencies with the the `--platform` flag.

Comment: I don't think that can work, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733542/how-to-use-the-same-python-virtualenv-on-both-windows-and-linux

Comment: @MilosStojanovic It can work if `pip` is used with the correct `--platfrom` flag

Comment: But then if I don't have internet connection in the linux laptop I can't really do this, right?

Comment: Yes, but he said that he doesn't have internet access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install packages offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline) See this [specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline/75811172#75811172)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running the script in the terminal with

`.venv/bin/python /directory/of/main.py`

This would help in determining if there is a problem with the activation or the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualenv is active after `source /project/venv/Scripts/activate`.
You need to install numpy into it, but the linux laptop has no internet.

A `pip install numpy` would be used if connected to the internet. You can proxy pip with a `~/.pip/pip.conf` file.

```
[global]
proxy = http://proxy:3128
```

If no proxy then you could build Numpy from source provide the linux laptop has a working C++ compiler and the development packages for your version of Python, and `wheel`.

Furthermore there are "build dependencies" distributed as wheels: packaging, meson, Cython, pyproject-metadata, meson-python, patchelf, ninja. These are collected at build-time, therefore an air-gapped build has additional challenges.