# Unable to install opencv-contrib-python deprecation Python 3.5

Tags: python, pip, opencv-contrib

I'm running Python in a virtual environment and within that I do:

```
python -V
```

Which returns:

```
Python 3.9.5
```

I then run:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

And get:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python
```

What commands do I need to run to get opencv to install if I am already on the latest Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this. It looks like it is because your virtual environment is using pip from python3.5

This was the message I had:

pip 20.3.4 from /home/user/virtproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)

This may be your solution:

python3 -m venv --upgrade ENV_DIR

ENV_DIR= your directory you installed the environment to.

[Upgrade python in a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218946/upgrade-python-in-a-virtualenv)