# How to install django with python3.9 on ubuntu aws

Tags: django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, python-3.9

I'm having challenges installing django using the command `sudo python3.9 -m pip install Django`. The error I get running that command is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(pip.main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 242, in main
    with self._build_session(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 66, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 321, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], platform.linux_distribution()),
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'
```

It's been a hard time trying to run `sudo python manage.py migrate`. From the comment/answer from this Stack Overflow post [Traceback while running 'sudo python3 manage.py migrate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062863/traceback-while-running-sudo-python3-manage-py-migrate/69062919?noredirect=1#comment122060678_69062919) I got to know that I need python 3.6 and above.  When I created the aws ubuntu server instance I ran `python3 -V` and the ouput was that python3.5 was running on the machine. I upgraded it to python 3.9. Now when I run `python3 -V` the output is: `Python 3.9.4`. After upgrading to python3.9  I created and activated another virtual enviroment.
Now when I try to install django using the command `sudo python3.9 -m pip install Django`  I get the above error. If I use `sudo python3 -m pip install Django` the django is installed with python3.5 because, thereafter when I run `sudo python3 manage.py migrate` it throws back an error pointing to `File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main`  If I delete python 3.5 in `/usr/lib` folder (since I still have python 3.9 there), python3.5 is recreated in the `/usr/lib` folder whenever I reinstall django using `sudo python3 -m pip install Django` (even if `python3 -V` is outputting `Python 3.9.4`). When I run `sudo python3 manage.py migrate` it says I don't have django installed in my enviroment variable.
Now the explanation is getting boring. PLEASE HOW DO I INSTALL DJANGO ON UBUNTU AWS USING PYTHON3.9?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo apt remove python3-pip
sudo python3.9 -m easy_install pip
```

then try to install django again

```
python3 -m pip install Django
```

Don't forget to create a virtual environment and specify the python version first

Comment: Thanks @ryan.chen. I have applied your recommendations but the same issue persists. After installing Django using the last command in your comment I'm not able to run `sudo python manage.py migrate`. When I try to migrate I get error message because  `sudo python3 -m pip install Django` is installing Django with python3.5  and not python3.9, even if `python3 -V` is outputting `Python 3.9.4` on the terminal just as I explained above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062863/traceback-while-running-sudo-python3-manage-py-migrate/69062919?noredirect=1#comment122060678_69062919 from comments of people from that stack overflow post I got to know that python3.5 doesn't support `asgiref` which is why migration isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I later found out that it is not possible to run `sudo python3.9 -m pip install Django`. As stated in the stack overflow post found in the link [Traceback while running 'sudo python3 manage.py migrate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062863/traceback-while-running-sudo-python3-manage-py-migrate/69062919?noredirect=1#comment122060678_69062919), python3.5 does not support it.

I had to install python3.6. I was able to use this python version to install django by runnig `sudo python3.6 -m pip install Django`.

I'm definitely not satisfied with these sorts of breaking changes that exist with python releases, but I'm glad I got the program running.